# Exception getting ignored (C# Form application)

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program where I need to write catch a null or general input exceptions with try...catch blocks, and make sure that the input is between two numbers with an if statement.

My problem is that the exception is getting ignored when I put in a null, string or other character, it just goes straight to the if statement. If I comment out the if statement, the exception still doesn't get caught.

```
const char DELIM = ',';
int input;
const int MIN = 1;
const int MAX = 10;
//convert the input to an integer
int.TryParse(tbInput.Text, out input);  
//check if the user has selected enter yet
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
    try
    {                                      
        //if the number entered is out of ranger, show error
        if (input < MIN || input > MAX)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter an integer between 1 and 10");
        }
        else
        {
            //if the number is in range, write to file
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file);
            writer.WriteLine(input.ToString() + DELIM + " ");
            writer.Flush();
            //flush the information to the file each time
        }
    }
    // any exceptions that occur will be caught here
    catch (IOException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error with input");
    }
    finally
    {
        //clear the taxtbox for the next entry
        tbInput.Clear();                    
    }
}
```

Here's my code. If someone could point out where I'm missing something, or what I should change, I'd really appreciate it. 
Cheers!

Comment: Which line are you expecting to throw the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[int.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a boolean value when checking the given argument. When the conversion attempt fails, `input` will have the default value assigned (0). Modify your code to check the result of `int.TryParse`.

```
if (int.TryParse(tbInput.Text, out input)) 
{
  // ok
}
else 
{
  // not ok
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that the exception is getting ignored when I put in a null, string or other character, it just goes straight to the if statement. If I comment out the if statement, the exception still doesn't get caught.

You are attempting to parse the input with a Integer.TryParse.  That method returns a boolean to indicate success (or lack thereof).  You aren't controlling the flow with the method, as I would expect.

Try

```
if (int.TryParse(tbInput.Text, out input))
```

Answer (score 1):

`int.TryParse` will never fail. It will return false if it doesn't succeed. You can do the following:

```
int input; 
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
    if (int.TryParse(tbInput.Text, out input) && input >= MIN && input <= MAX)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter an integer between 1 and 10");
    }
}
```

Or, you can just put `int.Parse` into your try catch and catch the `FormatException` and `OverflowException` (because it could fail). I will use `Convert.ToInt32`, as it's almost identical to `int.Parse`, but returns a 0 if the argument is `null` instead of throwing an `ArgumentNullException`.

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
    try
    {
        int input = Convert.ToInt32(tbInput.Text);
        ...
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Input was in an invalid format.");
    }
    catch (OverflowException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The input was outside the valid range for integers.");
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error with input");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're using `TryParse` instead of `Parse`. `TryParse` returns false, but does not throw an exception if parsing fails.

Try using:

```
input = int.Parse(tbInput.Text);
```

Comment: *and* they need to put that in the `try catch`. I don't think they understand that either.